# Store attribute error value in R for confusion matrix?

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I am very new to R and I wanted to know how can I store the classification error value which results from confusion matrix:
Example:

```
confusion(predict(irisfit, iris), iris$Species)

##            Setosa Versicolor Virginica 
##     Setosa     50          0         0
## Versicolor      0         48         1
##  Virginica      0          2        49
## attr(, "error"):
## [1] 0.02
```

I want to fetch the classification error value 0.02 and store it somewhere. How can I do that!?

Comment: Could you tell us which package you are using? It helps a lot if you can provide an example that's self contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your code works. You should be able to do the following

```
myconf<-confusion(predict(irisfit, iris), iris$Species)
myerr<-attr(myconf, "error")
```

which will put the value 0.02 in the variable myerr.